# Accidentally deleted external SSD

Tags: ssd, remote-disc

I accidentally deleted my external SSD using the delete function in Disk Utility, and now it does not show up using `diskutils list` in Terminal nor in Disk Utility. I have disconnected and reconnected the device and it does not show up in Finder. I have also attempted to restart my machine a couple of times.

The data on the disk is not really important I have other backups, but I would like to use my disk again.

How would one go about to access it?

Comment: if you plug in your disk, what does the command `diskutil list` give you?  Please post the output by editing the original question.

Comment: I did run the command, it did not show up, see my answer below.

Comment: There is no "disc utils", just Disk Utility and `diskutil`, so which one was it?

Comment: @user3439894 where do you see disc utils written? “diskutil list” is a command line program call.

Comment: @Solar Mike, The OP start of with "I accidentally deleted my external SSD using disc utils" and as I said there is no "disc utils", just Disk Utility and `diskutil`, so which one was it?

Comment: I will correct my post to clarify. Maybe my solution helps somebody else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing the USB port the external drive was connected to. I then rebooted my computer and all of a sudden I could access my external drive again. I do not really have an explanation why this worked however.